# Java CompletableFuture not giving result of the Callable's call()

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I've list of `Callable` which i want to `supplyAsync` to `CompletableFuture` , however when I do `join()` on the `CompletableFuture`'s, I get `null`

```
class CustomCallable implements Callable<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        return 2;
    }
}

List<Callable> callables = new ArrayList<>();

        callables.add(new CustomCallable());

        CompletableFuture<?>[] futures = callables.stream().map(x -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                return x.call();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        })).toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);



System.out.println(CompletableFuture.allOf(futures).join()); --> This line prints `null`
```

Comment: What does `allOf` return?

Comment: Or, in other words, what did you expect `join()` called on the result of `allOf` to return? Why?

Comment: Make sense. I think the right way is to `join()` on all `CompletableFuture` to get `List<Result>`

Comment: From javadoc of CompletableFuture.allOff: " the results, if any, of the given CompletableFutures are not reflected in the returned CompletableFuture"